# How can I convert strings from a text file into matrix (python)

Tags: python

For example:
content of `myfile` has

```
    fsdfasf
    frjfmcd
    39djaxs
```

I want to convert this in to a matrix where it consists of
my_matrix=[['f','s','d','f','a','s','f'],['f','r','j'......]]

I've tried reading the file using

```
for line in file:
        line = line.strip('\n)
        print(line)
```

But it's not giving me the desired output.

What am I missing to do?

Comment: Convert each line to a list (`list(line)` should do) and append each list to a final result list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn your string into a `list` to get the output you want. Since strings are sequences, when you pass a string to `list()` if breaks it up into individual characters:

```
with open(path) as file:
    matrix = [list(line.strip()) for line in file]
```

matrix:

```
[['f', 's', 'd', 'f', 'a', 's', 'f'],
 ['f', 'r', 'j', 'f', 'm', 'c', 'd'],
 ['3', '9', 'd', 'j', 'a', 'x', 's']]
```

Comment: thank you, this resolved my problem. I am not familiar with the notation you used for variable matrix. What is it called and how can I convert it into a notation that is "easier"

Comment: @RaeLeng that's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) — it's not to hard once you get used to it and it's pretty fundamental to python.